# Pattern Layout to abbreviate the name of all logger components except the 2 rightmost

Tags: log4j2

The following are my favorite patterns

> %c{2} - which displays the corresponding number of rightmost logger
>   name components. So a logger with a name like "org.apache.commons.Foo"
>   is displayed as "commons.Foo".

and

> %c{1.} - which abbreviates the name based on the pattern. So a logger
>   with a name like "org.apache.commons.Foo" is displayed as "o.a.c.Foo".

Is there a way to combine the two. I want to abbreviate the name of all logger components except the 2 rightmost. Such that "org.apache.commons.Foo" is displayed as "o.a.commons.Foo".

Is it possible to do this using the pattern layout or in any other easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. [NameAbbreviator.java](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/NameAbbreviator.java) handles creating the abbreviation of the name. It has a getAbbreviator method that returns one of 3 implementations -

1. NoOp - returns the string as is.
2. MaxElement - returns the last n elements.
3. Pattern - This uses the pattern to break up the string into fragments, formatting each according to the pattern. If you specify 1.2 then the first character of the first item will be printed and 2 characters of each following item will be printed up to the final token, which is never abbreviated. A special case is if the pattern contains a "*". That indicates that everything that follows should be printed as is.

So the answer to your question is that you could use the following patterns:

- 1.* - would print o.apache.commons.Foo
- 1.1.* - would print o.a.commons.Foo

As you can see this isn't very helpful when package names have different lengths. I would suggest you create a [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2) issue for this. Patches and pull requests are welcome!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you have suggested is a suitable workaround. I have also opened [Jira issue - LOG4J2-2785](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2785).